# RDMS with memcached or NOSQL database like MongoDB/CouchDB?

Tags: caching, memcached, couchdb, mongodb

Data in question would be mainly text with a one to many relationship (for example HTML pages) . I know that one can do "cache for x number of days" in memcached however how easy would that be to implement in NO SQL ?

Thank you again and I apologize in advance if I am not making sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to spec out your question much more for a meaningful answer.

In particular, unless you are dealing with a very large (many terabytes at least) amount of data, you'd be able to achieve your goals with either type of system without any significant trouble.  Just pay attention to your schema / index design on a RDBMS and it'll be at least comparable, and at best blow the pants off of your NoSQL solution, especially if you do anything more complicated than key/value lookups.

To me, it'd boil down to: which do you understand better?  I know PostgreSQL much better, so I'd use that, but your skills may differ...

--EDIT--

If all you're trying to do is *store* data, then just shove it in a text file or something.  It's how you intend to retrieve / process it that it gets interesting...

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I guess what I wish to store are Queries search results by a user in HTML text. So I would have tables like user id - search query - query results (pages).